# How to split text Python

Tags: python, split

Is it possible to put the particular text value in a single cell based on a text? For example, I have some texts that I need to separate and put in a single cell based on the keyword "sample story,"

i have tried with some split function which is not giving expected output
Eg: print(contents.split("sample story"))

```
sample story 1:
    
This is another great story that teaches a lesson that’s written for kids but that adults can enjoy, too. The story tells of a grasshopper who lounges around all summer while his friend the ant prepares for the winter. When winter comes, the two friends end up in very different situations!
    
The moral is that those who save up during good times will get to enjoy the benefits when times are bad.
    
    
Sample Story 2:
    
This very short story from India was originally written in Sanskrit (an ancient language). When a group of doves is caught in a hunter’s net, they must work together as a team to escape from the hunter’s clutches.
    
You can listen to a reading of the story as you read along on this website.
   
    
sample story 4:
    
1. This is a modern-day story about a little girl with a big secret she can’t tell anyone about. When her teacher finds out her secret, they work together to fix the issue.
2. This modern story is about a young woman named Penny who is anxious about going to her family’s annual reunion barbecue. But despite screaming children and arguing cousins, Penny ends up happy that she came to the reunion when she starts a conversation with a handsome man.
Note:   
This story is a good choice for absolute beginners because it uses only the present tense. It’s also written in very basic English with simple vocabulary and short sentences.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use regex to parse the string ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Rp4HYT/1)):

```py
import re
import pandas as pd

text = '''\
sample story 1:

This is another great story that teaches a lesson that’s written for kids but that adults can enjoy, too. The story tells of a grasshopper who lounges around all summer while his friend the ant prepares for the winter. When winter comes, the two friends end up in very different situations!

The moral is that those who save up during good times will get to enjoy the benefits when times are bad.


Sample Story 2:

This very short story from India was originally written in Sanskrit (an ancient language). When a group of doves is caught in a hunter’s net, they must work together as a team to escape from the hunter’s clutches.

You can listen to a reading of the story as you read along on this website.


sample story 4:

1. This is a modern-day story about a little girl with a big secret she can’t tell anyone about. When her teacher finds out her secret, they work together to fix the issue.
2. This modern story is about a young woman named Penny who is anxious about going to her family’s annual reunion barbecue. But despite screaming children and arguing cousins, Penny ends up happy that she came to the reunion when she starts a conversation with a handsome man.
Note:
This story is a good choice for absolute beginners because it uses only the present tense. It’s also written in very basic English with simple vocabulary and short sentences.'''

pat = re.compile(r'^(sample story \d+:)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=^sample story \d+|\Z)', flags=re.S|re.M|re.I)

out = pd.DataFrame(pat.findall(text), columns=['Header', 'Story'])
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
            Header                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Story
0  sample story 1:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             This is another great story that teaches a lesson that’s written for kids but that adults can enjoy, too. The story tells of a grasshopper who lounges around all summer while his friend the ant prepares for the winter. When winter comes, the two friends end up in very different situations!\n\nThe moral is that those who save up during good times will get to enjoy the benefits when times are bad.
1  Sample Story 2:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       This very short story from India was originally written in Sanskrit (an ancient language). When a group of doves is caught in a hunter’s net, they must work together as a team to escape from the hunter’s clutches.\n\nYou can listen to a reading of the story as you read along on this website.
2  sample story 4:  1. This is a modern-day story about a little girl with a big secret she can’t tell anyone about. When her teacher finds out her secret, they work together to fix the issue.\n2. This modern story is about a young woman named Penny who is anxious about going to her family’s annual reunion barbecue. But despite screaming children and arguing cousins, Penny ends up happy that she came to the reunion when she starts a conversation with a handsome man.\nNote:\nThis story is a good choice for absolute beginners because it uses only the present tense. It’s also written in very basic English with simple vocabulary and short sentences.
```